# Is it possible to show layouts in input-views?

Tags: bixby

Is it possible for an `input-view` to have a `form` and some layout below it? Would be nice to show some layout below a `text-input` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have layout with a form at this time.